# Iterate of two different dataframes efficiently on a specific column and store only the common rows

Tags: python, dataframe, spark-koalas

I have two dataframes as shown below.

```
import databricks.koalas as ks

input_data = ks.DataFrame({'code':['123a', '345b', '678c'],
        'id':[1, 2, 3]})

my_data = ks.DataFrame({'code':['123a', '12a', '678c'],
        'id':[7, 8, 9], 'stype':['A', 'E', '5']})
```

These two dataframes have a column called `code` and I want to check the values in column `code` that exist in `my_data` and also exist in `input_data` and store them in a resulting dataframe called `output`. The `output` dataframe will have only the `code` column values that are present in the input_data. The number of columns in each dataframe can differ and I have just shown a sample here

The `output` dataframe will have a result such as follows based on the provided sample in this question.

```
display(output)

# Result is below
 Code    id 
'123a'   7
```

I found solutions online that mostly use for loops but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to approach this.

Thank you all!

Comment: my mistake, it is koalas. Sorry for the error. I updated the question

Comment: I'm confused by what you want in the output. Originally you said that you want the column "code" for values that exist in both "input_data" and "my_data", but right after you say that the "output" dataframe will only have the "code" columns values that are present in the "input_data" dataframe. To clarify, do you want ONLY the rows where the "code" columns match up?

Comment: yes that is correct, I only want ONLY the rows where the "code" columns match up

Answer (score 0):

Can try using an inner merge on the two dataframes, and then on the new dataframe, just keeping the one column you want.

For example,

```
df_new = my_data.merge(input_data, on='code')
df_new = df_new[['code', 'id']]
```